# How to run git lfs automatically after repo sync

Tags: git-lfs, repo

We started to use git lfs recently, but many team members fogot to run git lfs after repo sync.
Is there any way could run git lfs after repo sync automatically?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no solution for this without modify the repo tool, but you always can create an alias (in GNU/Linux) in the file *~/.bash_aliases* or *~/.bashrc*:

```bash
alias repo-lfs="repo sync && repo forall -c git lfs pull"
```

Then source the file `source ~/.bash_aliases` and instead of using `repo sync`, use the `repo-lfs` command.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. Thank you so much.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! There are some extra chars though. Fixed: `alias repo-lfs="repo sync && repo forall -c git lfs pull"`

Answer (score 1):

There's a faster way. If you only run `git lfs pull` on directories that need it, it saves time for big repository trees.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Walk the entire tree starting at $PWD and find all directories
# containing `.gitattributes` file that says it's a Git clone
# directory that uses Git-LFS. For each such directory, do `git lfs
# pull`.
grep -l 'merge=lfs' $( find $PWD -name .gitattributes ) /dev/null | while IFS= read -r line; do
    dir=$(dirname $line)
    echo $dir
    ( cd $dir ; git lfs pull )
done
```